# HTTP POST REQUEST To PHP Server Android Studio

Tags: android

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
EditText editmsg , editmail ;
TextView content ;
String Message , Email ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editmsg = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMessage);
    editmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMail);
    Button btnsubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
    btnsubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                GetText();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                content.setText(" Url Exception!");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void GetText()throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    Message = editmsg.getText().toString();
    Email = editmail.getText().toString();

    String data = URLEncoder.encode("message", "UTF-8")
            + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(Message, "UTF-8");

    data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "="
            + URLEncoder.encode(Email, "UTF-8");

    String text = "";
    BufferedReader reader=null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try
    {

        // Defined URL  where to send data
        URL url = new URL("http://nitesh.com/feedback/add.php");

        // Send POST data request


        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write( data );
        wr.flush();

        // Get the server response

        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }


        text = sb.toString();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {

            reader.close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex) {}
    }

    // Show response on activity
    content.setText( text  );

}
```

}

I dont know what is wrong with code when i click the send button it showing Unfortunately,HTTP has stop (looking just like app crashed).
 please review my code and tell me what i have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see at once is that you are making your request in main UI thread (in `onCreate`). This is not allowed because network connections usually take some time to finish. There should also be an error message in the logcat about this.

What you should do is make your request in a separate thread. You can accomplish this by using `AsyncTask`, or `Thread`. Google it.

**UPD:**

Example on how to use Threads in Java. The method `run` will be executed asynchronously.

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){
    GetText();
  }
}).start();
```

Next time, please include the logcat errors in the question.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                  java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @Nitesh You get this because in your catch block, `content` is null. Define it in `onCreate`.

Comment: if you dont mind can you please correct my code . So that i can understand the whole situation

Comment: @NiteshKhaitan Sorry for a late reply. See an edit please.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using http://square.github.io/retrofit/ for network communication.

You will get a simple api and all request will be wrapped into correct thread.

Comment: If you are going to program for Android, you should get used to creating and doing things in different threads. Using a specialised library for that is an overkill

Comment: This is not a lib for threads but a type-safe HTTP client for Android and Java

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this task by using `AsyncTask`